# SOCKET.IO: Access cookies from devtools. Express-session

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

Why can't I access this cookie?[image]

When the user logs in the cookie is recieved and sent back to the Express server.

When initializing a new websocket to the Socket.io server this cookie does not get sent, so I was trying to get it via the `document.cookie`. However, it did not work since the the cookie was not modifiable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official website did something that did not work for me.
[express session middleware](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#compatibility-with-express-middleware)

```
const session = require("express-session");

io.use(wrap(session({ secret: "cats" })));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  const session = socket.request.session;
});
```

So, I got around it by making:
Logic:

```
Before establishing websocket, request credentials to express endpoint "/userCredentials"
and then use these credentials to establish the connection
```

Warning: Down below code is stripped because I did so many auth logics

```
CLIENT: 
...
useEffect(() => {
  (async() => {
    const pending_creds = await fetch("/userCredentials");
    const creds = pending_creds.json();
    
    const ws = io({auth: {creds}})
    
    setSocket(ws)
  })()
}, [])

...
```

```
SERVER:


...
app.get("/userCredentials", (req,res) => {
  const userSession = req.session.user;
  
  res.json(userSession)
})
...

io.use(socket, next){
  const creds = socket.handshake.auth.userSession;
  if(creds){
    next()
  } else {
    socket.disconnect()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an [HttpOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) cookie that cannot be accessed via client-side Javascript.

In other words: The *server* is able to read and manipulate the cookie. The *client* receives it and blindly sends it back with every subsequent request, without being able to read or manipulate its contents, at least not with Javascript means.

Comment: any tutorial on crash course for express-session/cookies you suggest I am so confused.

Comment: Start here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Comment: should I set this option to false, so I can pass this as an header for socket.io-client(socket.io-client does not have this cookie header)

Comment: but every request to the express API  is able to recieve this cookie header, idk why socket.io-client does not send this headerrr

Comment: or should I make const credentials = fetch("/getCredentials") request before the const client = io() initialization and then pass it as io({auth:{credentials}})

Comment: See my edited answer.